# Is there something similar to Fourier Series where the harmonics are division by n?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing

thanks for any help!
Do there exist any techniques relating to writing a periodic function as a sum of sines or other functions where the inputs to those functions are x/n (for some n) instead of n*x (n in Z) as in typical Fourier Series?

Why I'm thinking about this: working on synthesizer software.

Comment: Why would this help for synthesizer software?

Comment: Its relevant to my software.  To explain exactly why is far off topic because it relates to how I'm constructing the algorithms